# Best algorithm to validate that all items of one string array occur in another string array

Tags: c#, indexof, arrays

I have two string arrays, one containing file names like file1.docx, file2.docx, file3.docx and another array comes from UI controls and has to be like first one but having date added. I need to validate that all items of first array are present in second array (are parts of second array items strings).

```
foreach (UITestControl t in children)
{
    Boolean found = false;

    var div = t as HtmlDiv;
    if (div == null) continue;
    String actualText = div.InnerText;

    foreach (string t1 in searchResultNames)
    {
        if (!found)
        {
            if (actualText.IndexOf(t1, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            {
                found = true;
                result.AssertTrue(found, t1 + "found in search result");
            }
        }
    }
```

I use indexOf method but maybe this code can be improved somehow?

Algorithm used in our code turned out to be never fail:) because it always returns true if at least one item is found:) then it just goes through foreach loop with found value set to true and all is fine:) so i need to change this code

Comment: What kind of improvements are you looking for? Simplicity? Speed? Memory? Coolness?

Comment: "Best" implies speculation and subjectivity. You want to avoid that by explain what "best" means **for you**.

Comment: For speed, I'd recommend using a `Dictionary`

Comment: Determining best may also depend on some factors that you don't state. Is this a one-time search, or will it be repeated with a different array 1 or array 2? If it is repeated with different arrays, will there be overlap of members in the array 1 or array 2 of multiple runs? Will parallelism be likely to help?

Comment: Also, if the format in the second array is filename + date, then you might prefer to use string.StartsWith(), and you could probably construct a dictionary with the second array strings minus the dates. Is one array likely to be shorter than the other? Should they be the same length?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool allExist = !firstArray.Except(secondArray).Any()
```

**EDIT**

```
bool allExist = !firstArray.Except(secondArray, new MyComparer()).Any()
```

---

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.StartsWith(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj[0].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, Please comment what is wrong. I can edit/remove the answer if it's correct. Otherwise you only loose a `-1`. I still have a `+8`

Comment: i did not check you solution yet. will write when i try it out thx a lot for help. ps i did not say that it had not worked!!!

Comment: unfortunately ur algorithm does not work... nothing goes out of firstArray.Except(secondArray, new MyComparer()), no elements

Comment: string[] actual = new[] { "file1.docx17/04/2012", "file2.docx17/04/2012", "file3.docx17/04/2012" };

string[] expected =  new []{"file1.docx", "file2.docx", file3.docx"};

IEnumerable<string> temp = actual.Except(expected, new MyComparer()); - temp is empty...

Comment: @Alexander can you try by exchanging the contents of `actual` and `expected`?

Comment: i changed contents of arrays of course did not work. forget about it i found already easier solution for this task. thx for help...